# Web Site Zoom in - Zoom out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, refinerycms

What property I can modify, how and where, when I want to zoom out the entire web site.
The problem is when I open my web site - it´s just too "zoomed in". 
I´d like the entire pages to zoom out for about 10 %.
(Site is made with refineryCMS, ruby on rails)

Comment: You mean the browser zoom or a selfmade js zoom?

Comment: I wantfor everyone who comes on my site to be automatically zoomed out -10 %. Is there a property to set this?

Comment: You cannot modify the browsers zoom.

Comment: Are you talking about mobile clients?

Comment: no - it`s for desktop. Plain web site - like stackoverflow.com. I' just like to know is there a property for web developer i.e. that works for stackoverflow, and can he set that property so that when we all access this web site - it's zoomed out for all of us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a css property that controls the magnification level for the current element. The rendering effect for the element is that of a “zoom” function on a camera. Even though this property is not inherited, it still affects the rendering of child elements.

Example

```
div { zoom: 200% }
<div style=”zoom: 200%”>This is x2 text </div>
```

You could probably apply this to the body..

Comment: thx buzz. It works. i just have a problem when I open picture gallery - js. If I zoom it out on the right side I see some space...

Comment: @Dantes have any screenshots or anything i can take a look at?

Comment: Buzz Lightyear,thanks for your quick reply. Here is the screenshot (I marked the critical place with red arrows) http://tinypic.com/r/20tj78g/6

Comment: to remove margin and padding from HTML body but not the margin-right and etc....Just "Margin and padding".

You go to your CSS and add body{margin:0;padding:0;} and try it on all browsers.It should fit.